# Seeing Redis rolling back the transaction on EXEC however documentation says otherwise

Tags: redis, transactions

I have read in most places that Redis doesn't rollback the transactions. It is also mentioned in their documentation. Queries -

1. Why does it claim to be atomic then?
2. Refer screenshot below. It does indeed behaves like a rollback mechanism (the INCR a did not get processed or executed). What am I missing in understanding this behavior?

I am using version 3.0

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Atomic means that either all or none of the commands are executed. If there's an error, a data store with roll back would execute none; one without roll back would execute all, error or no. So in either case it's still an atomic operation.
2. This is explained in the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#errors-inside-a-transaction). There are two kinds of error:

> - A command may fail to be queued, so there may be an error before `EXEC` is called. For instance the command may be syntactically wrong...
> - A command may fail after `EXEC` is called...

In the first case, matching your example of an invalid command, Redis "will refuse to execute the transaction returning also an error during `EXEC`, and discarding the transaction automatically."

By contrast, "errors happening after `EXEC` instead are not handled in a special way: all the other commands will be executed even if some command fails during the transaction." This is the no-rollback-but-still-atomic scenario.